# Problem with twoside in article class

Tags: article, double-sided

I am writing a report in two columns with `\documentclass [10pt,twoside]{article}`. In the process a problem arose: including the statement `\twocolumn` the text in two columns jumps to the next page. How do I get the text to print on the same page?

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,left=0.7in,right=0.7in,top=0.5in,bottom=0.5in,footskip=.2in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx,lipsum}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\onecolumn
% Cabecera

\begin{flushleft}
\makebox[\textwidth]{\hrulefill}
\end{flushleft}
\begin{minipage}{0.2\textwidth}
%\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image} \\ \vspace{3.0cm}
\end{minipage} \hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.77\textwidth}\raggedright
\textbf{\color{olive}\huge\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont Opuntia: cuidado de agaváceas, cactáceas y crasuláceas} \\ \vspace{0.25cm}
{\large Arturo García Flores} \\ \vspace{0.1cm}
{\large Universidad Autónoma Metropolitana--Iztapalapa} \\ \vspace{0.25cm}
\today \\ \vspace{0.25cm}
\lipsum[1]
\end{minipage}%
\begin{flushleft}
\makebox[\textwidth]{\hrulefill}
\end{flushleft}

\twocolumn

\section*{Introducción}

\noindent \lipsum[1-7]

\end{document}
```

[image]

I used the multicol `package`, but for some reason the text doesn't wrap as I type.

I also used `\documentclass [10pt,twocolumn]{article}`, but the text in two columns is printed over the text in a column shown in the image (and which is a `minipage`).

Comment: Hello. Could you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that community members can reproduce your issue?

Comment: @DušanStokić Of course. I have added a part of my code in the question.

Comment: `\twocolumn` always starts a new page.   you  can put the initial text in the optional argument `\twocolumn[spanning text here]` or use the `multicol` package,

Comment: your question seems unrelated to the `twoside`  option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly you can either place the initial text in the optional argument of `\twocolumn` so that it spans the columns

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,left=0.7in,right=0.7in,top=0.5in,bottom=0.5in,footskip=.2in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx,lipsum}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\twocolumn[{
% Cabecera
\begin{flushleft}
\makebox[\textwidth]{\hrulefill}
\end{flushleft}
\begin{minipage}{0.2\textwidth}
%\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image} \\ \vspace{3.0cm}
\end{minipage} \hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.77\textwidth}\raggedright
\textbf{\color{olive}\huge\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont Opuntia: cuidado de agaváceas, cactáceas y crasuláceas} \\ \vspace{0.25cm}
{\large Arturo García Flores} \\ \vspace{0.1cm}
{\large Universidad Autónoma Metropolitana--Iztapalapa} \\ \vspace{0.25cm}
\today \\ \vspace{0.25cm}
\lipsum[1]
\end{minipage}%
\begin{flushleft}
\makebox[\textwidth]{\hrulefill}
\end{flushleft}

}]

\section*{Introducción}

\noindent \lipsum[1-7]

\end{document}
```

Or you can use `multicol` to allow switching to two-column mid-page

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,left=0.7in,right=0.7in,top=0.5in,bottom=0.5in,footskip=.2in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx,lipsum,multicol}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

\begin{document}


% Cabecera

\begin{flushleft}
\makebox[\textwidth]{\hrulefill}
\end{flushleft}
\begin{minipage}{0.2\textwidth}
%\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image} \\ \vspace{3.0cm}
\end{minipage} \hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.77\textwidth}\raggedright
\textbf{\color{olive}\huge\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont Opuntia: cuidado de agaváceas, cactáceas y crasuláceas} \\ \vspace{0.25cm}
{\large Arturo García Flores} \\ \vspace{0.1cm}
{\large Universidad Autónoma Metropolitana--Iztapalapa} \\ \vspace{0.25cm}
\today \\ \vspace{0.25cm}
\lipsum[1]
\end{minipage}%
\begin{flushleft}
\makebox[\textwidth]{\hrulefill}
\end{flushleft}

\begin{multicols}{2}

\section*{Introducción}

\lipsum[1-7]

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow. I feel terrible when the solution is as simple as pressing ```[]```. XD

Thanks everyone for your help.